# How to identify a doomed horoscope(Jatakam)

Tags: karma, astrology

In astrology there are sayings if these planets are placed in these houses then the person has good life, wealth and health but this is the positive side in astrology.

In general if there is positive aspects there in should be a negative aspects too.

All I need to know is the planetary positions for the respective signs which denotes that the person is doomed to suffer forever in his life.

Comment: too broad a question

Comment: There can be many such combinations which make a chart "doomed" .. so kind of broad .. already 2 close votes as I write this comment

Comment: But no combinations is that bad ... each one has respective remedies

Comment: @Rickross, atleast top 5 then ?

Comment: I m not sure , let's wait to see if the Q gets closed or not .. if it gets closed u can think of revising it for re-opening @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM

Comment: @Rickross sure thank you, if this question gets closed where is the right place/person to find results specific to a particular Horoscope? Thank you

Comment: I am not sure, better go for a good astrologer ... do not rely on answers that u get on sites like this .. some basic websites are also there like astrosage, astrobix etc @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM

Comment: 5th house called "_puthira sthanam_ & _poorava punniya sthanam_" if there is **sani** or **raghu** or **kethu** or else any these are joined in that house they will get

Comment: @ssr1012 I don't understand. The horoscope has Sun, Mercury, Venus and Raghu all occupying 5th house

Comment: 9 planets are called Navagraha. 3 planets are called **asubar sani, raghu and kethu** should not be occupied by single or joined the 5th house owned by God "**Suriya**".

Comment: @ssr1012 so it is occupied by 4 gods what to do?

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM: please check with the comments from [Rickross](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/34125/how-to-identify-a-doomed-horoscopejatakam?noredirect=1#s)

Answer (score 2):

A horoscope is doomed either it is afflicted with malefic combinations(Yogas) or aspects leading to immoral character, poverty, diseases or untimely death.

When the lords of gains houses that are ascendant, 2,5,9,11 exchange positions with dusthana houses 6,8,12 it leads to loss of wealth in rivalry, diseases and wanderings.

[Combinations for Penury](http://jyotishvidya.com/ch42.htm)

> 2. The native will be penniless if the ascendant lord is in the 12th as the 12th lord is in the ascendant along with a Maraka lord (death
>      inflicting planet) or be in aspect to such a planet.
> 3. The native will be penniless if the ascendant lord is in the 6th while the 6th lord is in the ascendant with conjunction or aspect of a
>      Maraka lord.
> 4. Should the ascendant or the Moon be with Ketu while the ascendant lord is in the 8th, the person concerned will be penniless.
> 5. If the ascendant lord along with a malefic is in the 6th, 8th, or 12th, while the 2nd lord is in an enemy's sign or in debilitation,
>      even a native of royal scion will become penniless.
> 6. If the ascendant lord is conjunct an evil house (one of the 6th, 8th, and 12th lords) or Saturn and be devoid of benefic aspect the
>      native will be penniless.
> 7. Should the 5th and 9th lords be respectively found in the 6th and 12th and be in aspect to Maraka planets, the native will be penniless.

Death is mainly associated with 3rd and 8th house and presence of Maraka planets in them and hemming of luminaries by malefics and association with nodes and Dusthana houses leads to premature death or family disruptions.

[Evils at Birth](http://jyotishvidya.com/ch9.htm)

> 15. EARLY DEATH: Should all the malefics be in the oriental half while benefics are in the occidental half, early death of one born in
>       Scorpio will follow.
> 16. Malefics in the 12th and the 6th, or in the 8th and the 2nd, while the ascendant is hemmed between other malefics will bring early death.
> 17. Malefics occupying the ascendant and the 7th while the Moon is conjunct a malefic with no relief from a benefic will also cause
>       premature death.
> 18. Early death will be inflicted on the native if decrease in Moon is in the ascendant while malefics capture the 8th and an angle. There is
>       no doubt about that.
> 19. The Moon in the ascendant, 8th, 12th, or the 7th and hemmed between malefics will confer premature death.
> 20. Should the Moon be in the ascendant hemmed between two malefics while the 7th or the 8th has a malefic in it, the child will face
>       immediate death along with its mother.
> 21. Should Saturn, the Sun and Mars be in the 12, 9th, and 8th without benefic's aspect, the child will face instant death.
> 22. With a malefic in the 7th house or in the rising decanate while decreasing Moon is in the ascendant, death will be expected early.
> 23. The life span of the child will be either 2 months or 6 months only, if all planets devoid of strength are relegated to Apoklima
>       houses (i.e. 3rd, 6th, 9th, and 12th).

[Maraka Planets](http://jyotishvidya.com/ch44.htm)

> THREE KINDS OF LIFE SPANS: short, medium, and long. 10-14. O Brahmin,
>   I tell you further about Marakas. Narrated earlier are three kinds of
>   life spans, viz. short, medium, and long. Short life is before 32
>   years, later on up to 64 it is medium life, and from 64 to 100 it is
>   long life. Beyond 100 the longevity is called supreme. O excellent of
>   the Brahmins, it is impossible to decide upon longevity till the
>   native is 20 years old. Till such year the child should be protected
>   by sacred recitations, religious offerings (of ghee etc. to
>   consecrated fire as prescribed by Vedas etc.) and medical treatments,
>   for premature death may descend on the child due to sins of father or
>   mother or of its own (in the previous birth).   15-21. I further
>   mention about the Maraka planets. One born with short life
>   combinations may face death in the Dasa denoted by Vepat star (3rd
>   from birth star); one of medium life may die in the dasa denoted by
>   Pratyak star (5th from birth star). In the dasa denoted by Vadha star
>   (7th from birth star), one with long life may obtain his end. The dasa
>   of the lord of 22nd decanate or the one of 23rd, 3rd, 5th, or 7th
>   asterisms may also cause death. The lords of the 2nd and 12th counted
>   from the Moon sign may bring death, this is true when the said ruler
>   is a malefic and if he be a benefic there will be (only) diseases (but
>   not death). Death may come to pass in the dasa of 6th lord and in the
>   sub periods of 6th,8th, and 12th lords. Should there be many Marakas
>   (endowed with the power of killing) and be strong, there will be
>   diseases, miseries etc. in the respective major and sub periods. Thus
>   these are Marakas (as above) and are primarily related to descend
>   death upon the native. According to their dispositions there may be
>   death or difficulties.
>
> NODES: RAHU AND KETU AS MARAKAS: If Rahu or Ketu be in the ascendant,
>   7th, 8th, or 12th thereof, or be in the 7th from a Maraka lord or be
>   with such a planet, they acquire powers of killing in their major or
>   sub periods.
>
> 25-31. THIRD HOUSE AND DEATH: O excellent of Brahmins, if the Sun,
>   being with strength, is in the 3rd house from the ascendant, one will
>   obtain his death due to a king (or legal punishments). The Moon in the
>   3rd will cause death due to tuberculosis while wounds, weapons, fire,
>   and thirst will cause death through Mars in the 3rd. If the 3rd be
>   aspected or occupied by Saturn and Rahu, death will be through poison,
>   water or fire, or fall from heights or confinement. Death will surely
>   come to descend through insects or leprosy if the Moon and Gulika
>   occupy or aspect the 3rd house. Mercury aspecting or occupying the 3rd
>   will bring death following fever. Jupiter in the 3rd or aspecting the
>   3rd will cause death by swelling or tumors. Urinary diseases will
>   cause death if Venus is in the 3rd or aspects the 3rd. Many planets
>   aspecting or occupying will bring death through many diseases.
>
> 35-36. OCCUPANTS OF THE 8TH HOUSE: Note the occupant of the 8th house
>   from the ascendant. If it is the Sun, death will be through fire, the
>   Moon water, Mars weapons, Mercury fever, Jupiter diseases, Venus
>   hunger, and Saturn thirst.

Other than these, conjunctions of the node Rahu with other important planets like Sun, Jupiter, Mars, Saturn creates Pitra, Guru-Chandal, Angarak, Shrapit Dosha respectively each having different negative impacts on the person. Further, lot of aspects like strengths, dashas of planets are also to be analyzed before concluding, whether the effects(good and bad) of specific formation will unwind fully or its countered by other formations.